# Is this a bug in Bot Builder V4 SDK Template for Visual Studio

Tags: botframework

I wonder if this is a bug [Bot Builder V4 SDK Template for Visual Studio](https://botbuilder.myget.org/feed/aitemplates/package/vsix/BotBuilderV4.fbe0fc50-a6f1-4500-82a2-189314b7bea2). As shown in the screenshot below, the builds with the small size do not include the actual project template and cause confusion. Only the ones with the size 426 KB or larger work.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a bug.  We are tracking the issue in our [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1101).  Please track this bug over there.

Comment: This just caught me out completely. An hour and half gone ...

Comment: No idea what you mean.  The SDK is only on v4 ...

Comment: @Jammer Bot SDK 4 is covered under so many bugs. Its design does not make any sense neither. Dialog are hardcoded and defined in C# code.